# VB.NET SQL Server connection

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a small Windows forms project, with a SQL class, which connects to our SQL Server database to perform simple select/update queries.

I have a simple form with a button, which, when pressed, runs a select query to populate a DataGridView.

The query looks in the database at a certain table, for a certain value in a given column, and returns the matching records.

This all works fine for my sample set of data. If I run the query (with no matching values in the source table) the DGV is empty. If I close the project, add some matching fields to the source table, reopen the project and run again the DGV is populated with the new matching records.

The problem comes from modifying the source table, while the program is open. If I run the query with no matching records the DGV is empty. However, if I add some matching fields and rerun the query again (without closing the program) the DGV remains empty until I close and reopen the project?

Is there some auto caching that takes place I need to remove?

Comment: Can you post your code? hard to help without seeing it.

Comment: What you mean by "rerun the query again"? Are you re databinding gridview?

Comment: How are you telling the DGV that the data has changed? The standard way of doing this is databinding the DGV to the dataset via a BindingSource. In this scenario the grid will automatically update when the data is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the datasource on the fly?
Try this:

> ```
> Dim strCN As String = My.Settings.InovaConnectionString
> Dim cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(strCN)
> Dim ds As New DataSet
> Dim DataAdapt As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Code, Name, City  FROM CUSTOMERS where Nome_Cliente like 'Carl%' ", cn)
> DataAdapt.Fill(ds, "CUSTOMERS")
> CUSTOMERSDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables("CUSTOMERS")
> ```